# Better documentation and instructions for Mirth upgrades?

Tags: mirth

Several days ago, Mirth Connect version 3.3.0 was released. Noting the [great new features](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/Mirth+Connect+3.3.0+-+What's+New), we decided to upgrade immediately (just days after the initial release). We followed these [Upgrade Guide](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/Mirth+Connect+Upgrade+Guide) instructions during the upgrade. However, the specifics of upgrading from 3.2 to 3.3 are missing from these Upgrade Guide, so we did not suspect much to change on the way Mirth should be implemented...

During this process, we ran into [a handful of issues](https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?p=51794#post51794) that caused our production channels to go down for several hours (†).

It would have been really nice to have specific information for this upgrade. Some issues that would have been really useful to know beforehand (just examples, no need to actually answer):

- Are you changing the default toString() method for objects/arrays to return JSON representations?
- Does this upgrade include a db migration, meaning we can't revert to
  previous version once upgraded?
- Because code templates are now children of "libraries", will we need to access the code template through the library, or will we be able to call it directly (as it was in 3.2)?

A solid documentation like this would have allowed us to understand the full gravity of what needs to be accounted for when upgrading. Typically, Mirth has *some* documentation for each minor release. But even then, the documentation is very terse. **Would it be possible for the Mirth team to start being very explicit with what the upgrade entails?**

The [Rails Upgrade Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) (obviously much larger team, so can spend more bandwidth on this spec) provides a really great example of what an upgrade guide should entail.

† *yes, yes, I learned my lesson, I won't upgrade immediately to production anymore*

Comment: @NickRupley I think you might be able to help on this one!

Answer (score 1):

The [Release Notes](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/Mirth+Connect+3.3.0+-+Release+Notes) page will give the lowest level of changes to the application, but you're right in that a better documentation is needed.